# How to make downloaded Python libs work on Windows?

Tags: python, libs

I got this simple problem and I can't find the answer anywhere, I'm wasting a lot of time!

I did a Python programm on Linux (which works OK), but when I try to run it on Windows, there are too problems with libs...

I have installed the libs I need (dateutil, lxml, xmlrpclib...) in C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages. But then, they don't work as they do on Linux. For example:

```
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
```

Gives me next error:

> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz.py", line 9, in module
>   from six import string_types, PY3 ImportError:  No module named 'six'

That is, they are not finding the other modules... why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try this ?

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-Python-packages-on-Windows-7/

Maybe it can help

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't done the installation before, but now the problem is that in the middle of it, this breaks with the same errors I got if I run my programm.

Comment: Where exactly does it break ?

Comment: For example, with the library xmlrpclib breaks with this error (in line 193):

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xmlrpclib.py", line 193
    MAXINT =  2L**31-1
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: xmlrpclib isn't a Pyhton 3.4 lib it has been replace by xmlrpc.client I think this is why you get some syntax error

Comment: You were right, I stopped using xmlrpclib and now I am using xmlrpc.client on Kubuntu and it works as well as before. But on Windows is still returning errors. But I am closer. Thank you very much!

Comment: GREAT!!! Last error on Windows was a stupid mistake by me, but now I fixed it, and xmlrpc.client works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Python 3.4 which comes with `pip`.  `pip` is a tool for installing packages and any dependencies they might have (like the `srting_types` module from your error message).  I'd suggest learning how to use it because it resolves most of the packaging problems with you needing to moving things around yourself.  See [an answer from a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/21182892#21182892) to learn more about `pip`.

There are some packages that need to be compiled.  This can be difficult on Windows 7 if you don't have the proper toolchain set up to compile packages.  I'd recommend Christoph Gohlke's [wonderful collection of installable packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for Windows.  You just need to make sure to grab the right version.  Since 3.4 is still relatively new, some packages may not be available, so be warned.

Comment: You are right, I used pip and I solved the problem with dateutil and six libraries. However, with lxml and xmlrpclib I get errors. For example, with xmlrpclib I get this:   Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external xmlrpclib to allow).

Comment: I managed to install lxml without pip and now it works. But I can't find xmlrpclib for Windows anywhere.